# github - find pull requests with empty description

Tags: github

How can I perform a search on github to find pull requests within a repository which have no description?

When viewing these PRs, the description says "*No description provided.*" in italic text

I believe the description is also referred to as the "body"
https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues-and-pull-requests/#search-by-the-title-body-or-comments